# Serialize Generic JSON with jackson

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, jackson

I want to serialize my POJO class, when produce output to XML, it work perfect as what I want. 
But not for the JSON.

My main POJO class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="result")
@XmlSeeAlso({ResultDataRowItemTest.class})
public class ResultDataRowTest {
   private ResultDataRowItemTest response;

   public ResultDataRowTest() {}

   public ResultDataRowItemTest getResponse() {return response;}

   public void setResponse(ResultDataRowItemTest pst) {this.response = pst;}

}
```

ResultDataRowItemTest class:

```
public class ResultDataRowItemTest<T> {
   private T item;

   public ResultDataRowItemTest() {}

   @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
   @XmlElements({
   @XmlElement(name="user", type=RetUser.class)
   })
   public T getItem() {return item;}

   public void setItem(T pst) {this.item = pst;}
}
```

RetUser class :

```
@JsonTypeName("user")
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class RetUser {
   private int userID;
   private String userName;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public String getUserName() {return userName;}
   public void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}

   public int getUserID() {return userID;}
   public void setUserID(int userID) {this.userID = userID;}

   public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {this.firstName = firstName;}

   public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {this.lastName = lastName;}

}
```

Result for the XML:

```
<result>
  <response>
    <user>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Pantau</lastName>
        <userID>5</userID>
        <userName>JohnP</userName>
    </user>
  </response>
</result>
```

Here's the result for the JSON :

```
{"response":{
  "item":{
    "user":{
        "userID":5, 
        "userName":"JohnP", 
        "firstName":"John", 
        "lastName":"Pantau"
    }
  }
}}
```

The problem is, how to remove object "item" for JSON ? So the result just like XML.

So much thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are making use of JAXB for XML and Jackson for JSON.

Take a look at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics you might need to pass generic type definition.

You need to specify Jackson annotation in ResultDataRowTest.

Comment: that's right, I create rest service using spring. So I have to create POJO class for the return/response. and so far it works with XML. Still looking for JSON with jackson. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by specify jackson annotation?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you need to really care much whether JSON and XML look alike -- they are different formats with different logical models (object vs hierarchic), and used with different tools. It's perfectly fine for two to look bit different, ideally both look good for format itself (i.e "clean XML" and "clean JSON").

But as to 'item': it will be there if you have accessor (getItem()). If you don't want it, you can flatten your structure.

Also, I don't know why you are using generic type parameter T, since you don't really make any use of it. Could as well just use `Object` as type. Shouldn't really hurt, just saying that it does not seem useful in this case.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I concern for the documentation that will make **different** response/return for XML and JSON. in that example above, my `T` object only receive for `RetUser.class`, but in the real code, it receive most of my pojo class.

Comment: Hi @StaxMan, I have tried using @JsonUnwraped for the `item` object, but it doesnt work. Maybe I have to accept the reality, that the response for both XML and JSON are not always the same. Thanks for your thought